# How to jump to a particular column in SQL Developer table view?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Suppose I have a table with 300 columns. I open a table in SQL developer and apply a filter(through UI widget) on one of the first columns. Now, I need to check the value of a particular column for the filtered row(I know the name of the column). At the moment I have to search for the column by scrolling right, but it's tedious. Is there a better approach? I know about <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> but it's only for values in columns, not columns itself as far as I know.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way today.

You can hide the 290 columns you rarely look at however.

Right click on the column header, select Columns, and then remove the ones getting in your way.

[image]

I don't need to see these columns 99% of the time...

[image]